# Adding a custom button to WordPress Add Post (and Edit Post too) screen, that can save the post

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a plugin that hides the publish box from authors, so that I can have them click on a button in a custom meta box I created, to save their post. (This is not the sole purpose of the plugin, rest, I can't share. But this step is needed to do the rest.)

I want WordPress to save the post to DB as it normally would, when I click on that button.

How do I invoke WordPress' post save action from a custom button?

Comment: Perhaps the better option is to hook into [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) to do the things you want?

Comment: @Zogot: That won't help as I _have_ to hide the publish box. Without the publish box, no publish button, no firing of save_post action.

Anyway, the solution was more obvious. I should have tried it before posting here. But anyway, someone who is stuck like I was might find this helpful. I am posting the solution as the answer to this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution couldn't be more obvious.

The Add New Post screen is a one big form. Any `<input type="submit"/>` element you put in it will save the post.